# Type hinting closures for Laravel collections/models

Tags: php, laravel, types, closures, type-hinting

I have been looking into type hinting my PHP code to meet the PSR guidance but am slightly confused as to what to do in terms of passing down an instance of a model to a function. See a random example below...

```
public function interactWithOrder($order, $basket)
{
    return;
}
```

For the code above, $order would be a collection of data for a singular order pulled from the model & basket being an array. What would be the correct way of type hinting this? My suggestion is below...

```
public function interactWithOrder(mixed $order, array $basket)
{
    return;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

> what to do in terms of passing down **an instance of a model** to a function

> $order would be **a collection of data** for a singular order pulled from the model

It depends on which one it is.

- Is `$order` an `Order` model? (`$order = Order::where(...)->first();`)
- Is it a `Collection` of `Order` models? (`$order = Order::where(...)->get();`)

If `$order` will always be an `Order` model, then just type hint it as such.

```php
public function interactWithOrder(\App\Models\Order $order, array $basket)
```

`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $order` should also work.

If `$order` will always be an `Order` `Collection`, (even if it's a single order) then just type hint it as such.

```php
public function interactWithOrder(Collection $order, array $basket)
```

`Collection` could be `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` (specific) or `Illuminate\Support\Collection` (would work with both because `Eloquent\Collection` extends from it)

How do you plan on using the function?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! 

When i've tried passing down an instance of Auth::user() and in the closer using (User $user) it throws an error of - Expected \App\Models\User, got \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable 

is there a way around this just using the model instance or would it just be best to leave it as ($user)

TIA :)

Comment: Weird. It works on my end. Does `dump(get_class(Auth::user()))` return `'App\Models\User'`?

Comment: Yes it does, it might just be a visual my IDE is showing up. Will probs be fine then! Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe your IDE's reading the return type of the `Auth::user()` function, which is `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null`. It should be fine since `Authenticatable` is an interface implemented by the default `App\Models\User`model.